# jwplayer 6.1: controls show up for youtube videos despite controls: false

Tags: jwplayer

i am using jwplayer 6.1, in the player setup i've set

```
controls: false
```

however, there is sth odd going on...

**youtube videos:** i do get a controlbar for the split of a second that then disappears (see screenshot).
**mp4-videos:** i don't get this controlbar and all is fine.

how can i get rid of the "flashing" controlbar for youtube videos?

[image: i quickly captured this odd controlbar]

Comment: I just checked this with 6.1 on my localhost and I could not replicate. Do you have a link that demonstrates this behavior? I was checking in Win7, FF 19, Flash 11.

Comment: i'll try and provide you with a showcase asap, unfortunately the site i am working on is not live so i'll have to isolate the problem :)

Comment: i've created a showcase and uploaded it here: http://www.file-upload.net/download-7331236/jwplayer.zip.html

we animate the video from a width/height of 1px to its original dimensions. as you can see during the animation the controls flicker up quickly :)

tested in FF 19.0.2 on Win 7 (64 bit) with flash 11.6.602.180

Comment: I see that now. This seems to only happen if you are using jQuery and animation though. It doesn't happen with a normal stock embed though and the flicker is so quick that it is barely noticeable though.

Comment: @EthanLongTail yep it only happens when the video is animated...so you think it's probably a youtube issue?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is probably an issue with YouTube + Animation. Do you get the same issue if you don't use YouTube as the source?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer - without youtube link , In flash same problem occurs and In HTML5 video is not visible, only player control and audio is heard

Comment: Have you tried to update to 6.8 from 6.1?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the issue in different scenarios and saw the same problem and found one work around for this, see below

I AM USING `jwplayer.version="6.8.4616"`

### **Problem**

> SAME FUNCTIONALITY WITHOUT YOUTUBE LINK

Primary : HTML5 => [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/QZ3Ye/7/)

Primary : flash => [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/QZ3Ye/8/)

> SAME FUNCTIONALITY WITH YOUTUBE LINK

Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/QZ3Ye/5/)

### **Solution :**

SAME FUNCTIONALITY WITH YOUTUBE LINK

http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/QZ3Ye/26/

you can try doing the animation in `onReady` instead of doing in `onPlay` **which solves your problem.**

```
onReady: function(){
                      console.log('player: onReady');
                      player.animateResize(width, height);  
                   }
```

> **But this is just a fix for youtube video but if you try doing same
>   animation without youtube links, Issue still exist.**

### **SAME FUNCTIONALITY WITHOUT YOUTUBE LINK**

Primary : HTML5
http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/QZ3Ye/14/

primary:flash 
http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/QZ3Ye/27/

Hope this helps you.